# AttributeError: module 'h11' has no attribute 'Event'

Tags: python, events, attributeerror

`

```
Already up to date.
venv "C:\StableDiffusion\stable-diffusion-webui\venv\Scripts\Python.exe"
Python 3.8.0 (tags/v3.8.0:fa919fd, Oct 14 2019, 19:37:50) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]
Commit hash: 828438b4a190759807f9054932cae3a8b880ddf1
Installing requirements for Web UI
Launching Web UI with arguments:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "launch.py", line 251, in <module>
    start()
  File "launch.py", line 242, in start
    import webui
  File "C:\StableDiffusion\stable-diffusion-webui\webui.py", line 13, in <module>
    from modules import devices, sd_samplers, upscaler, extensions, localization
  File "C:\StableDiffusion\stable-diffusion-webui\modules\sd_samplers.py", line 11, in <module>
    from modules import prompt_parser, devices, processing, images
  File "C:\StableDiffusion\stable-diffusion-webui\modules\processing.py", line 15, in <module>
    import modules.sd_hijack
  File "C:\StableDiffusion\stable-diffusion-webui\modules\sd_hijack.py", line 10, in <module>
    import modules.textual_inversion.textual_inversion
  File "C:\StableDiffusion\stable-diffusion-webui\modules\textual_inversion\textual_inversion.py", line 13, in <module>
    from modules import shared, devices, sd_hijack, processing, sd_models, images, sd_samplers
  File "C:\StableDiffusion\stable-diffusion-webui\modules\shared.py", line 8, in <module>
    import gradio as gr
  File "C:\StableDiffusion\stable-diffusion-webui\venv\lib\site-packages\gradio\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    import gradio.components as components
  File "C:\StableDiffusion\stable-diffusion-webui\venv\lib\site-packages\gradio\components.py", line 31, in <module>
    from gradio import media_data, processing_utils, utils
  File "C:\StableDiffusion\stable-diffusion-webui\venv\lib\site-packages\gradio\processing_utils.py", line 20, in <module>
    from gradio import encryptor, utils
  File "C:\StableDiffusion\stable-diffusion-webui\venv\lib\site-packages\gradio\utils.py", line 35, in <module>
    import httpx
  File "C:\StableDiffusion\stable-diffusion-webui\venv\lib\site-packages\httpx\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from ._api import delete, get, head, options, patch, post, put, request, stream
  File "C:\StableDiffusion\stable-diffusion-webui\venv\lib\site-packages\httpx\_api.py", line 4, in <module>
    from ._client import Client
  File "C:\StableDiffusion\stable-diffusion-webui\venv\lib\site-packages\httpx\_client.py", line 29, in <module>
    from ._transports.default import AsyncHTTPTransport, HTTPTransport
  File "C:\StableDiffusion\stable-diffusion-webui\venv\lib\site-packages\httpx\_transports\default.py", line 30, in <module>
    import httpcore
  File "C:\StableDiffusion\stable-diffusion-webui\venv\lib\site-packages\httpcore\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from ._api import request, stream
  File "C:\StableDiffusion\stable-diffusion-webui\venv\lib\site-packages\httpcore\_api.py", line 5, in <module>
    from ._sync.connection_pool import ConnectionPool
  File "C:\StableDiffusion\stable-diffusion-webui\venv\lib\site-packages\httpcore\_sync\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .connection import HTTPConnection
  File "C:\StableDiffusion\stable-diffusion-webui\venv\lib\site-packages\httpcore\_sync\connection.py", line 13, in <module>
    from .http11 import HTTP11Connection
  File "C:\StableDiffusion\stable-diffusion-webui\venv\lib\site-packages\httpcore\_sync\http11.py", line 44, in <module>    class HTTP11Connection(ConnectionInterface):
  File "C:\StableDiffusion\stable-diffusion-webui\venv\lib\site-packages\httpcore\_sync\http11.py", line 140, in HTTP11Connection
    self, event: h11.Event, timeout: Optional[float] = None
AttributeError: module 'h11' has no attribute 'Event'
Appuyez sur une touche pour continuer...
```

`

Hello everyone
I'm a newbie trying to use Stable Diffusion :'(
I tried to launch it for the first time but it got stuck each time to this error, I honestly don't really know what i'm supposed to do right now.

Answer (score 3):

Seems you have to reinstall httpcore in version 0.15

> pip install --force-reinstall httpcore==0.15
> works as a temporary workaround until some other fix is found.
> That or just append it to your requirement.txt
> This comes from a recent update in httpcore and nothing related to this repository.

Source: https://github.com/AUTOMATIC1111/stable-diffusion-webui/issues/4833

Comment: Thank you very much, but it still doesn't work :'(

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue by adding the below line in pipfile

```
httpcore = "<=0.15"
```

that is the solution for who using pipenv

Comment: What pipfile? 2 more characters?

Answer (score -1):

Don't feel bad, for me it starts right up in windows. But I've tried several distros and installations since Aug and it has never run once.

update:I kept banging away at it, and it finally worked!
[I just made this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SGnZC.png)
I ran it with "python launch.py" and every time an error popped up I searched for it and applied the recommended fix...good luck!

Comment: This is not an answer, it should have been a comment.